# Is it possible to manipulate the data in a matplotlib histogram using Get and Set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, matlab-figure

I have a stacked histogram made using matplotlib. It has of course multiple bins (on per sector) and each bin/bar is further segmented in subsectors (stacked histogram).

I'm wondering how I could get the datapoints, do some math (let's say divide each bin by it's total value), and than set the new datapoints.

**How I expect it to work:**

```
import matplotlib.plt as plt
ax = plt.subplt(111)
h = ax.hist((subsector1,subsector2,subsector3), bins = 20, stacked=True)

y_data = h.get_yData
```

*The shape of y_data would be something like 20 x 3 (bins x subsectors)*

```
new_y_data = y_data normalized by total on each bin
```

*The shape of new_y_data would also be like 20 x 3, but the sum on each bin would be 1 (or 100%)*

```
new_h = h.set_yData(new_y_data)
```

*new_h would look more like a bar plot, with equal sized bars, but different subsector distributions on each bar..*

Is this even possible in python matplotlib?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data points from a histogram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128898/get-data-points-from-a-histogram-in-python)

Comment: Partially, as it covers the 'get' part of the question. I also need to add these point (after some modification) into the hist. Meanwhile I'm trying to see if I can build some bar plot with the result..

Comment: Once you have all data and styling you can recreate the plot yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want the values, it's easier to use [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) which does the same calculations without the need to draw.

When you have values, [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) draws the directly without needing [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Pandas [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) might be an alternative. Have a look at [Creating percentage stacked bar chart using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433876/creating-percentage-stacked-bar-chart-using-groupby) for an example similar to yours.

Here is some example code using `np.histogram` and `plt.bar`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

subsector1 = np.clip(np.random.normal(70, 20, 400), 0, 100)
subsector2 = np.clip(np.random.normal(50, 20, 1000), 0, 100)
subsector3 = np.clip(np.random.normal(25, 20, 500), 0, 100)
num_bins = 20
x_min = np.min(np.concatenate([subsector1, subsector2, subsector3]))
x_max = np.max(np.concatenate([subsector1, subsector2, subsector3]))
bounds = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, num_bins + 1)
values = np.zeros((num_bins, 3))
for i, subsect in enumerate((subsector1, subsector2, subsector3)):
    values[:, i], _ = np.histogram(subsect, bins=bounds)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    values /= values.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bottom = 0
for i in range(3):
    plt.bar((bounds[:-1] + bounds[1:]) / 2, values[:, i], bottom=bottom, width=np.diff(bounds) * 0.8)
    bottom += values[:, i]
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1.0))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: This answers my question (short answer is 'no') and provides a good alternative solution. Thank you! One comment tho, Matlotlib's plt.hist does indeed have a stacked= option.